# Download files from SharePoint library folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, file

I have SharePoint Online site and library with folders.

There are folder like YEAR / Month / 16 June / files inside.

What would be the best way to download files from this folders?

I can use C# or VBS.

---

At this moment I am trying to Connect they application using C# SharePoint Client
Have sharepoint user name and password.

It seems like I am not able to get auhtorized with some reasons.
Got following exception:

> Exception: Cannot contact web site 'https://mypage.sharepoint.com/' or
> the web site does not support SharePoint Online credentials. The
> response status code is 'Unauthorized'

Is there something do authorize me app?

Comment: Do you want to download it from any custom application only or you are fine with SharePoint OOTB suggestion?

Comment: No, I just want to download them from they library into hard drive folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download a folder and all folders/files inside it then you can do it from SharePoint UI.

- Go to SharePoint library
- Select folder
- Click on **Download** from top ribbon
- It will download a zip file with folder and its contents

[image]

**Microsoft documentation**: [Download files and folders from OneDrive or SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/download-files-and-folders-from-onedrive-or-sharepoint-5c7397b7-19c7-4893-84fe-d02e8fa5df05)

**Update from Comments**:

Check this reference to download files programmatically: [Download files from document library using C#](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105921/download-files-from-document-library-using-c)

Comment: But it needs to be done from application side not manually

Comment: What type of application you have? console application/.Net application or any other application?

Comment: You can also use [PowerShell solution](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/07/download-folder-from-sharepoint-online-using-powershell.html) or [PnP PowerShell solution](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/download-files-from-sharepoint-online-document-library-folder-to-shared-network-drive-system-file-path-using-sharepoint-pnp-powershell) if you are OK with it.

Comment: Its simply .NET framework console application. And SharePoint Client library.

Comment: I need this like a simple console app to be invoked from other application.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to store info on SharePoint is to dismiss folders instead of metadata and after create views acts like a folder.

Answer (score -1):

Check if the following references are helpful:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/06/cannot-contact-website-url-web-site-does-not-support-sharepoint-online-credentials-response-status-code-unauthorized.html

https://www.assistmyteam.com/kb/cannot-contact-web-site-https-xxxx-sharepoint-com-or-the-web-site-does-not-support-sharepoint-online-credentials/

Comment: Thank You! I will test this a bit later because waiting to resolve authentication issues first.